# Compile error when using CriteriaBuilder

Tags: java, generics, jpa

I am trying convert this JPA QL to criteria builder. JBoss 6.0.

```
"SELECT ba FROM BankAccount ba WHERE ba.balance >= :amt ORDER BY ba.ownerName ASC"
```

I wrote this code according to several tutorials.

```
public List<BankAccount> findWithBalance(int amount) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<BankAccount> cq = cb.createQuery(BankAccount.class);
    Root<BankAccount> from = cq.from(BankAccount.class);

    ParameterExpression<Integer> balance = cb.parameter(Integer.class);
    cq.select(from);

    Predicate predicate = cb.gt(from.get("balance"), balance);
    cq.where(predicate);

    cq.orderBy(cb.asc(from.get("ownerName")));

    TypedQuery<BankAccount> query = em.createQuery(cq);

    return query.getResultList();
}
```

But, I am getting a compile error in the line:

```
Predicate predicate = cb.gt(from.get("balance"), balance);
```

The error is:

```
The method gt(Expression<? extends Number>, Expression<? extends Number>) in the type CriteriaBuilder is not applicable for the arguments (Path<Object>, ParameterExpression<Integer>)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, I finally found the right way to call the gt() method. Here is the complete solution. Fully tested in JBoss 6.

```
public List<BankAccount> findWithBalance(int amount) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<BankAccount> cq = cb.createQuery(BankAccount.class);
    Root<BankAccount> from = cq.from(BankAccount.class);

    ParameterExpression<Integer> balance = cb.parameter(Integer.class);
    cq.select(from);

    //Here is the trick!
    Predicate predicate = cb.gt(from.<Integer> get("balance"), balance);

    cq.where(predicate);
    cq.orderBy(cb.asc(from.get("ownerName")));

    TypedQuery<BankAccount> query = em.createQuery(cq);

    query.setParameter(balance, amount);

    return query.getResultList();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The type safety feature in JPA restricts such comparisons with incompatible types, the compiler itself will raise error.

Here, `from.get("balance")` returns the `Path<Object>`, but the method can accept parameter of type `java.lang.Number`, therefore results in error.

You can try the below code.

```
//--
    Metamodel metamodel = em.getMetamodel();
    EntityType<BankAccount> pClass = metamodel.entity(BankAccount.class);
    Predicate predicate = cb.gt(from.get(pClass.getSingularAttribute("balance", Integer.class)), balance);
//--
```

If you are using Metamodel API, then you can retieve directly by specifying ClassName_.field as `cb.gt(from.get(BankAccount_.balance), balance)` which is much cleaner & easy to debug.

But if you are having many entities, then it may be difficult to write their Metamodel classes manually, if the JPA provider doesn't generate them.

Comment: I made that change. The new error is:


The method gt(Expression<? extends Number>, Expression<? extends Number>) in the type CriteriaBuilder is not applicable for the arguments (SingularAttribute<capture#1-of ? super BankAccount,Integer>, ParameterExpression<Integer>)

Comment: I posted my answer. Please see above.

Comment: @RajV Yes, its much better +1

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is complaining because `amount` is an `int`, not an `Expression`, see if you can figure out how to build an `Expression` that's a constant and use that and you should be good.

Comment: Can you edit your post with the revised code and give the error message you are currently getting. I can't imagine you are getting the same error if you are using an arg that is a ParameterExpression. And also doing that is probably not what you want.

Comment: I updated the code and the new error message. What I am doing is straight from various tutorials. I don't think criteria query can be done in JBoss 6.