# What does it mean: "from.<Integer>"?

Tags: java, generics, syntax, expression

I saw a question about criteriaBuilder and came up with this question...

What does it mean `from.<Integer> get("...`?

I've never seen a point before of the expression `<Integer>`.

Could somebody show me an example?

Link: [Compile error when using CriteriaBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10390115/compile-error-when-using-criteriabuilder/21317287)

Code:

```
public List<BankAccount> findWithBalance(int amount) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<BankAccount> cq = cb.createQuery(BankAccount.class);
    Root<BankAccount> from = cq.from(BankAccount.class);

    ParameterExpression<Integer> balance = cb.parameter(Integer.class);
    cq.select(from);

    //Here is the trick!
    Predicate predicate = cb.gt(from.<Integer> get("balance"), balance);

    cq.where(predicate);
    cq.orderBy(cb.asc(from.get("ownerName")));

    TypedQuery<BankAccount> query = em.createQuery(cq);

    query.setParameter(balance, amount);

    return query.getResultList();
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a call to a generic method with `Integer` passed in as a type parameter.

See here:

[Java-syntax for explicitly specifiying generic arguments in method calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012781/java-syntax-for-explicitly-specifiying-generic-arguments-in-method-calls)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12

Comment: As far as I know Java infers them whenever it can do so, are there any reasons why it would not be able to do so? (In this case, or in general, maybe some Java versions are worse at it?)

Comment: This is when you specify it explicitly.

Comment: Maybe you should post how whole the class Root<BankAccount> looks like. I guess you would get more concrete answers this way.

Comment: @skiwi if by "some Java versions" you mean "some implementations", there shouldn't be any difference from one implementation to the next, because the type inference rules are spelled out by the Java Language Specification.

Comment: @ajb I more meant Java 5, 6, 7, 8, etc. Especially since the code seems to come from a company (or just example code), it is not unreasonable ot think they are still using Java 5 or 6.

Answer (score 2):

The angle brackets are for Java generics. In most cases, the type of the generic can be inferred, but not always. See [Type Inference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html) for a discussion of this topic. The example they use is:

```
void processStringList(List<String> stringList) {
    // process stringList
}

processStringList(Collections.emptyList()); // Compile error!
processStringList(Collections.<String>emptyList());  // Ok!
```

Apparently in Java 8, this is no longer an issue since the compiler will infer types from method arguments as well.

Answer (score 0):

From **`Java Generics and Collections`**,

```
List<Integer> ints = Lists.<Integer>toList(); // first example
List<Object> objs = Lists.<Object>toList(1, "two"); // second example
```

1. `In the first example`, without the type parameter there is too little information for
   the type inference algorithm used by Sun's compiler to infer the correct type. It infers
   that the argument to toList is an empty array of an arbitrary generic type rather than
   an empty array of integers, and this triggers the unchecked warning described earlier.
   (The Eclipse compiler uses a different inference algorithm, and compiles the same line
   correctly without the explicit parameter.)
2. `In the second example`, without the type parameter there is too much
   information for the type inference algorithm to infer the correct
   type. You might think that Object is the only type that an integer
   and a string have in common, but in fact they also both implement
   the interfaces Serializable and Comparable. The type inference
   algorithm cannot choose which of these three is the correct type.

### **In general, the following rule of thumb suffices:**

**In a call to a generic method, if there
are one or more arguments that correspond to a type parameter and they all have the
same type then the type parameter may be inferred; if there are no arguments that
correspond to the type parameter or the arguments belong to different subtypes of the
intended type then the type parameter must be given explicitly.**

***Some points for passing type parameter***

When a type parameter is passed to a generic method invocation, it appears in angle
brackets to the left, just as in the method declaration.

The Java grammar requires that type parameters may appear only in method invocations that use a dotted form. Even
if the method toList is defined in the same class that invokes the code, we cannot
shorten it as follows:

```
List<Integer> ints = <Integer>toList(); // compile-time error
```

This is illegal because it will confuse the parser.