# Java criteria API - select * from table where id = id

Tags: java, sql, criteria-api

I am new to the criteria api and am trying to build a select query where id matches id.

I would like to build this:

```
SELECT * FROM movie WHERE id = id(input var)
```

So far I have this with an input variable id as a `long`:

```
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Movie> critQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Movie.class);
    Root<Movie> rootMovie = critQuery.from(Movie.class);
    critQuery.select(rootMovie).where(rootMovie.get("movieId"), id);
```

This will create errors and doesn't work. Any ideas how to make it work?

error:
The method where(Expression) in the type CriteriaQuery is not applicable for the arguments (Path, Long)

Comment: Add the error messages please.

Comment: I don't know how the API is supposed to work, but you're missing a close parenthesis in `critQuery.select(rootMovie).where(rootMovie.get("movieId", id);` -- does `get` actually take two arguments?

Comment: made a little typo + added the error

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10390115/compile-error-when-using-criteriabuilder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `where` condition should look like this:

```
.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(rootMovie.get("movieId"), id));
```